# Thunderbird not accepting Apple RSS feeds

Tags: rss

I'm trying to subscribe to an Apple RSS feed. 
Thunderbird keeps telling me that Apple RSS feed URLs are invalid. 
For example, I can't subscribe to feed://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss 
Can I fix this problem, or is it just a problem with Apple's feeds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using http://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss instead of feed://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss.

Comment: Thanks, that does work. I thought I had tried that already, but I guess not! Thank you